# Select in template does not update in edit

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the following code below, which would be the editing of a form of a request I made here for my work, as I had to change some of the views my update has to be manual, and the select field is not getting the result that I'm bringing it from the db, all fields are working except the select.
[as it is now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nvaHY.png) ||| [as should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avqAw.png)

```
class EditPedido(View):
    def get(self, request, venda):
        data = {}
        venda = fixa.objects.get(id=venda)
        data['filial'] = venda.regional
        return render(request, 'fixa/fixa_update.html', data)
```

```
<select name="filial" class="select form-control" required="" id="filial">
    <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
    {% for filial in filiais %}
        <option value="{{ filial.id }}">{{ filial.nome }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

**EDIT**

```
class EditPedido(View):
    def get(self, request, venda):
        empresa_logada = request.user.funcionario.empresa
        data = {}
        data['filiais'] = empresa.objects.filter(nome=empresa_logada)
        venda = fixa.objects.get(id=venda)
        data['filial'] = venda.regional
        return render(request, 'fixa/fixa_update.html', data)
```

```
<select name="filial" class="select form-control" required="" id="filial">
    <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
    {% for filial in filiais %}
        <option value="{{ filial.id }}">{{ filial.nome }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'create_fixa' %}">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <h2>number do Pedido: {{ sell.number }}</h2>

        <p><font color="RED">{{MSG}}</font></p>

        <hr>
        <br>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3 mb-0">
                <label for="number">Nº da Simulação</label>
                <input type="text" name="number" class="form-control" value="{{number}}" required="">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-9 mb-0">
                <label for="razao">Razão Social</label>
                <input type="text" name="razao" class="form-control" value="{{razao}}" required="">
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="form-row">

            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                <label for="razao">CNPJ</label>
                <input type="text" name="cnpj" class="form-control" data-mask="00.000.000/0000-00" value="{{cnpj}}" required="">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                <label for="tipo">TIPO</label>
                <select name="tp_cli" class="select form-control" required="" id="tp_cli">
                    <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
                    <option value="FRESH">FRESH</option>
                    <option value="BASE">BASE</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-row">

            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                <label for="razao">Filial</label>
                <select name="filial" class="select form-control" required="" id="id_regional">
                    {% for filial in filiais %}
                    <option value="{{filial.id }}">{{ filial.nome }} {% if filial.id == filial %}selected{% endif %}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                <label for="tipo">Indicação</label>
                <select name="indicacao" class="select form-control" id="indicacao">
                    <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
                    {% for indicacao in indicaoes %}
                    <option value="{{ indicacao.id }}">{{ indicacao.nm_primeiro_nome }} {{indicacao.nm_segundo_nome}}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                <label for="tipo">Status</label>
                <select name="status" class="select form-control" id="status">
                    <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
                    {% for statu in status %}
                    <option value="{{ statu.id }}">{{ statu.nome_st }}</option>
                    {% endfor %}
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br>

        <input type="hidden" value="{{sell.id}}" name="sell_id">

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Salvar</button>
    </form>
```

```
class EditOrder(View):

    def get(self, request, sell, *args, **kwargs):

        company_entered = request.user.employee.company
        parent_company = request.user.employee.company.company_pai

        data = {}
        data['status'] = tb_status.objects.all()
        sell = fixa.objects.get(id=sell)

        if parent_company:
            data['filiais'] = company.objects.filter(nome=company_entered)
            data['indicaoes'] = employee.objects.filter(cargo__nome='Vendedor', company__nome=company_entered)
        else:
            data['filiais'] = company.objects.filter(nome=company_entered) | company.objects.filter(
                company_pai=company_entered)
            data['indicaoes'] = employee.objects.filter(cargo__nome='Vendedor')

        data['number'] = sell.number
        data['razao'] = sell.nm_razao
        data['cnpj'] = sell.nr_cnpj
        data['tp_cli'] = sell.tipo_cli
        data['filia'] = sell.regional_id
        data['indicacao'] = sell.indicacao
        data['sell'] = sell
        data['family'] = tb_tp_prod.objects.all()
        data['type'] = tb_tipo_servico.objects.all()
        data['qtds'] = tb_qtd.objects.all()
        data['itens'] = sell.itemdopedido_set.all()

        return render(request, 'fixa/fixa_update.html', data)
```

Comment: To what endpont do you make the POST request to edit the record?

Comment: How does filiais get defined? You have a for loop in your template that references it but I don't see how it is set.

Comment: Excuse-me did not understood your question.. @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: @Deepstop, i edited the question, but,  filiais is saved in my dB I made the save in the form of registration.
I am recovering through the variable "venda" that after the items of my db, I have never done this way I always did through the "updaveView" but in this case I need to do this.

Comment: When you do "view source" on the page, do you see any <option> tags other than the first one?

Comment: @Deepstop, YES, I see all the inputs however, none comes set default as it is in "UpdateView"

Comment: @Deepstop, I insert 2 img in question, look, please..

Comment: I have a form that correctly shows a default value in the box, and it uses: <option value="CAD" selected="selected">CAD</option>. I don't know if what you are doing is wrong, but this example certainly works.

Comment: @Deepstop in HTML

<select name="filial" class="select form-control" required="" id="filial">
                    <option value="" selected="">---------</option>
                    
                    <option value="1">TESTE</option>          
                    <option value="2"> SOROCABA</option>                    
                    <option value="5"> MARILIA</option>                    
                    
</select>


but none is selected when I pull the dB value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is what you had in your last comment (I don't know where the space before the words in the third and fourth options are coming from, but perhaps you should remove them)

```
<select name="filial" class="select form-control" required="" id="filial"> 
<option value="" selected="">--------</option> 
<option value="1">TESTE</option>
<option value="2"> SOROCABA</option>
<option value="5"> MARILIA</option>
</select>
```

You have the 1st option selected, which is --------. I think you want this

```
<select name="filial" class="select form-control" required="" id="filial"> 
<option value="1">TESTE</option>
<option value="2"> SOROCABA</option>
<option value="5" selected=""> MARILIA</option>
</select>
```

You will have to indicate to the template which option to select, you could pass this as a variable something like

```
data['selection'] = 5
```

Then in the template

```
<option value="{{ filial.id }}" {% if filial.id == selection %}selected=""{% endif %}>{{ filial.nome }}</option>
```

I'm not certain about the syntax of the {% if filial.id == selected %} statement. I don't use it much but the idea is to just put the tag in the option that requires it.

Comment: I changed, but doesn't work, when removing the ----- he began to select by default the first one the "TEST"

about your answer : data['selection'] = 5 
i used :                     data['filial'] = venda.regional_id

where "filial" is the name attribute in HTML

Comment: So if you look at page source, did the MARILIA option have selected="" in it? Also, I just noticed I typed "Selected" in the if statement instead of "selection". I will update the answer.

Comment: i used "selection" but nothing, 
I'm sorry to bother you.

<div class="form-group col-md-6 mb-0">
                <label for="razao">Filial</label>
                <select name="filial" class="select form-control" required="" id="filial">
                    
                    <option value="1">TESTE </option>                    
                    <option value="2">SOROCABA </option>                    
                    <option value="5">MARILIA </option>

                </select>
  </div>

Comment: I had {% if filial.id == selection %}selected=""{% endif %} in the wrong place, but I think you still have a problem. The variable "selection" doesn't seem to be triggering the if statement, because the text selected="" does not appear. I just tried this myself and it worked.

Comment: i don't know what do. 
because, other fields, its work, but only selected is wrong.

Comment: i updated my question with template and code..
If you missed something let me know.

Comment: I don't see the changes we have discussed in that code you just posted. In the template, <option value="" selected="">---------</option>, will do exactly what you are describing, fill --------- as the default for the drop downs. You need to have selected="" in the option which you want to select.

Comment: I'm so sorry, when i'll posted i forgot to exclude this part, but i did, this.
in others part no, only in FILIAL...

Comment: OK. 2 things. First, please change this line <option value="{{filial.id }}">{{ filial.nome }} {% if filial.id == filial %}selected{% endif %}</option> to <option value="{{filial.id }}"  {% if filial.id == filial %}selected{% endif %}>{{ filial.nome }}</option>. Second, make sure your view has a statement data['selection'] = 5, so that the if statement in the template will add selected="" to the MARILIA option.

Comment: mannnn, its work,  with 
<option value="{{filial.id }}" {% if filial.id == filial %}selected{% endif %}>{{ filial.nome }}</option>
you're awesome.. help me so much..

Comment: Great! if you want to do that for the other inputs, you might want to do something like data['selection'] = { 'filial': 5, 'indicacao': 3, ... } for the key for each of the inputs, then {% if xxxxx.id = selection.xxxxx %} for each of them.

Comment: Also please select the check mark on this answer to show your question has been answered. Thanks.